# How to consume a signed assembly (PCL) in a Xamarin iOS project?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library, strongname

My solution references a project (.csproj included in solution) that has lately been code signed. Now I get an error when building:

> Error CS1548: Error during assembly signing. The specified key file
>   `code-signing-2014.pfx' has incorrect format (CS1548)

What do I have to do to get this working again (Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recall `mcs` supporting PKCS#12 files (can you open a bug report ?) but Mono's version of `sn` itself should.

> What do I have to do to get this working again (Xamarin Studio / Visual Studio)?

That should already work inside Visual Studio, where `csc` is used, right ? otherwise there might be an issue with the file itself.

For Xamarin Studio (`mcs`) the easy workaround is to disable the assembly signing (in the project options).

A more complex workaround is to extract the key out of the .pfx file and create a *classic* .key file that `mcs` will accept. You'll need to write a small tool to do so (using `Mono.Security.dll`) since I'm not aware of any existing tool that does this specific conversion.